# Future Builder not building

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to include `FutureBuilder` but it goes into the `CircularProgressIndicator()` and doesn't load the actual screen code after the value of 'time' is populated by calling from SharedPreferences and the  `ConnectionState` is `done`. It just gets stuck in the CircularProgressIndicator().

What am I missing here?

```
Future<int> getTime() async {
  await MySharedPreferences.instance.getIntValue("time_key").then((value) =>
    setState(() {
     time= value;
}));
     return time;
        

      @override
 void initState() {
super.initState();

MySharedPreferences.instance
    .getStringValue("title_key")
    .then((value) => setState(() {
  title = value;
}));



controller =
    AnimationController(vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds: time));
controller2 =
    AnimationController(vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds: time));
controller3 =
    AnimationController(vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(
            seconds: 1));
    ....}
      
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

            return WillPopScope(

              onWillPop: () async => false,
              child: Scaffold(

                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                body: FutureBuilder<int>
                  (
                  future: getTime(),
                builder: ( BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                  print(snapshot);
                  print(time);
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    print(time);
                    return SafeArea(

                      minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child:
                            Align(
                              alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 1.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: MediaQuery
                                      .of(context)
                                      .size
                                      .height / 2,
                                  width: MediaQuery
                                      .of(context)
                                      .size
                                      .height / 2,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    //shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      image: DecorationImage(

                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            "assets/images/moon.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          build_animation(),
                          

                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }


                  else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                }


                  ),
  ),
            );
        }


build_animation() {
  return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 1.0,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[

                                  Text(
                                    title.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                                  ),
                                  new Container(
                                    child: new Center(
                                      child: new Countdown(
                                        animation: new StepTween(
                                          begin: time,
                                          end: 0,
                                        ).animate(controller),
         .....
```

Comment: as i see the code `FutureBuilder` builds and even multiple times, add `print(snapshot`) before `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: It's printing the following message continuously:flutter: AsyncSnapshot<int>(ConnectionState.waiting, 17, null) . Why is it stuck in waiting state? Am I doing something wrong with:        Future<int> getTime() async {
    await MySharedPreferences.instance.getIntValue("time_key").then((value) =>
        setState(() {
         time= value;
    }));
 return time;
  }
I need the 'time' value (which is an int) from the shared preferences . This value is used for duration of the Animation controller in the Build.

Comment: `Future<int> getTime() => MySharedPreferences.instance.getIntValue("time_key")`

Comment: Yes, that solves the ConnectionState.waiting issue,  but it is not updating the time value to the value obtained from shared preference. Any ideas?

Comment: you are not using `time` variable in the future builder code you posted

Comment: I have updated the code to include the usage of 'time' variable.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you do not need to `setState` for the result of the Future you use with a FutureBuilder. The whole point of the FutureBuilder class is to handle that for you. Also, it's best to not mix `.then()` and `await` until you have more experience. They work well together, but concentrate at one concept at a time while you are still learning.

This is your method after it's trimmed down (your choice if that's still worth a method, or if your want to put that code into `iniState` directly):

```
 Future<int> getTime() async {
    final value = await MySharedPreferences.instance.getIntValue("time_key");
    return value;
 }
```

You should *not* give that method to your FutureBuilder, otherwise you will start it anew every time `build` is called for any reason.

So you `initState` should look like this:

```
Future<int> futureIntFromPreferences;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  futureIntFromPreferences = getTime();
}
```

Then you can use that in your `FutureBuilder`:

```
body: FutureBuilder<int>(
        future: futureIntFromPreferences,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
```

For a detailed explanation, read [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: thanks...your explanation makes things easier to understand. However, I am still not able to update the value of the 'time' variable (for the animation controller.) Is it even allowed to update the controller duration value with a Future Builder?